# What does "static" imply on constant within an enum or struct

Tags: swift, struct, enums, constants

I recently came across the following:

```
enum MyEnum {
  static let myVariable = "some value"
}

struct MyStruct {
  static let myVariable = "some value"
}
```

and wonder what the `static` implies. To my understanding `let` already implies the immutability which is then shared by all instances of the `enum`/`struct`. It sounds to me that this is micromanaging memory consumption, but I'm not sure that I'm missing the underlying point here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means `myVariable` is a [type property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264) – a single property that all instances of the type can use. Essentially a global variable associated with `MyEnum`.

In the case of constants declared with `let`, this is a way of declaring constants that are scoped to the type that don’t take up space within each instance of that type, i.e.:

```
struct MySlimStruct {
    static let myVariable = "some value"
}

sizeof(MySlimStruct)  // returns 0

struct MyFatStruct {
    let myVariable = "some value"
}

sizeof(MyFatStruct)  // returns 24
```

In the case of static variables declared with `var`, this is a good way of introducing undiagnosable bugs and crashes into your program.

Comment: so it is indeed memory management?! Is there a use case for the `MyFatStruct` instead of the `MySlimStruct`?

Comment: yes, if you want each instance to have it’s own value for `myVariable`

Comment: @Airspeed Velocity, do you think you could expand on your last comment a little?